# How to find if an document can be OPENed via ShellExecute?

Tags: c++, winapi, shellexecute

I want to check if a particular file can be successfully "OPEN"ed via ShellExecute, so I'm attempting to use AssocQueryString to discover this.

Example:

```
DWORD size = 1024;
TCHAR buff[1024];  // fixed size as dirty hack for testing

int err = AssocQueryString(0, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE, ".mxf", NULL ,buff , &size);
openAction->Enabled  = ((err == S_OK) || (err == S_FALSE)) && (size > 0);
```

Now, this *almost* works. If there's a registered application, I get the string.

But, there's a catch: On Vista, even if there is no registered application, It returns that the app c:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll is associated, which is the thing that brings up the 100% useless "Windows cannot open this file: [Use the Web service to find the correct program](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/skip-the-annoying-use-the-web-service-to-find-the-correct-program-dialog/)?" dialog.

Obviously I want to hide that peice of cr*p from end users, but simply comparing the returned string to a constant seems like an ugly, brute-force and fragile way of doing it.

Also, hacking the registry to totally disable this dialog  isn't a great idea.

What's a better option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always use [`FindExecutable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776419(VS.85).aspx) to get the registered application for a given document.

Comment: Thanks - works perfectly, and "fails" correctly if no application is registered. Kicking myself for not finding this one...

Comment: Had to revisit this due to Samba performance issues. Posted the answer that I'm now using below.

Answer (score 4):

There is another way to do this, using the `ASSOCF_INIT_IGNOREUNKNOWN` option flag with `AssocQueryString()`.

```
int err = AssocQueryString(ASSOCF_INIT_IGNOREUNKNOWN, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE, ".mxf", NULL ,buff , &size);
```

This has a couple of important advantages over using `FindExecutable()`

- It can work with just the file extension, while `FindExecutable` needs a full path to an existing file of the specified type.
- Because it's not accessing the file, it's much faster with Samba and other network storage. Calling `FindExecutable()` on one file in a directory containing ~3000 files via Samba took > 1 second in my tests.

Comment: I'm confused. You originally said you had a problem with Vista, and now you say you have a viable solution using the ASSOCF_INIT_IGNOREUNKNOWN flag, which according to MSDN was introduced with Windows 7. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762471(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, `AssocQueryString` is more reliable than `FindExecutable` (it also doesn't require an existing file): http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/10/13/finding-an-associated-executable.aspx. As for the `ASSOCF_INIT_IGNOREUNKNOWN` flag, if you need pre-Win7 support I actually like your idea in the deleted answer of using some GUID as an extension to get the "no association" handler (actually that was my first thought when I saw your question).